# Laravel8 Model Injection in Controller with Relationship

Tags: laravel

I have 2 models: `Company` and `Category`

`Company` has many `Categories`, and `Category` belongs to `Company`

```
// App\Models\Company.php

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

and

```
// App\Models\Category.php

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

All ok with relationship, now I have a route

```
/company/{company}/category/{category}
```

And in the controller I have the next code:

```
public function foo(Company $company, Category $category)
{
    ///
}
```

And I get a 404 not found. I think it is because the relationship between Company and category fails.

If I do the next:

```
public function foo($company, Category $category)
{
    dd(
       Company::find($company)->categories()->where('id', $category->id)->first(),
       $category
    );
}
```

I get the correct Category in both way, so, the relationship in model I guess is ok. Also, I can add/remove with relationship, so again, I guess is ok.

Now, my question is, how I can inject 2 model with relationship in the controller?

Cuz all way I'm getting error 404.

Thanks!

Comment: The 404 means one of the models was not found, and is nothing to do with the relationship between them.

Comment: @miken32 If I do in controller (Company $company, $category) = works, ($company, Category $category) = works. But if I do the 2 inject, it fails.

Comment: The routing engine has no interest in relationships, it's simply doing a database lookup on both items separately. Checking database query logs might give you some idea why it fails in some situations.

Comment: There's nothing stopping multiple bound parameters, but generally in CRUD URLs you don't want any kind of hierarchy indicated anyway. e.g. your URL should probably just look like `/category/{category}` since the info on the company can be derived from the category.

Comment: Seems like your `{company}` parameter doesn't match with your `companies` table `id`

Comment: I notice it doesn't match with relationship.  And @Droid all data match with table id. The weird thing is, with I put both injection it fails. If I call with a `findOrFail($company)` or `findOrFail($category)` it found all data correctly.

Comment: I thought if I put 2 inject it checked the relationship but doesn't

Comment: What is in your log file?